# pythonのif構文でor使用時に、orが3つある最初にある分岐が優先されてしまう

Tags: python

私は、人材募集広告から文字列検索をし、カテゴリー分けをしています。
不揃いな言葉の中からカテゴリー分けをしているのですが、if 構文で以下のようにorで3つ分けてしまうと、返り値が、すべて"物流STAFF"になってしまいます。

この現象がなぜ起こっているかご指導をお願いします。

```
【sample】
work_explain = '【シール貼り/おまけ付け】登録制★来社不要のWEB登録♪日払い'
work_explain = '【倉庫内作業】登録制「Wワーク・学校の合間を有効活用◆'

def work_category(work_explain):

    works = ['箱詰め','組付','袋詰め','検査','資材運搬','ガスの充填',
    '包装','景品交換','品質管理','ドライバー助手','鮮魚スタッフ','配送アシスタント',
　　'食品加工','調理補助','荷下ろし', '荷捌き',　'資材運搬','施工管理','地盤改良',
'中古住宅インスペクション','清掃','地盤調査','物流STAFF','タオルたたみ','ペットボトルの分別']

    if "箱づめ" in work_explain:
        work_explain = '箱詰め'
    if "品だし" in work_explain:
        work_explain = '品出し'

    if "資材運び" or "資材を運ぶ" in work_explain:
        work_explain = '資材運搬'
    if '工場STAFF' or '物流倉庫' or '倉庫業務' or '工場staff' or '倉庫内作業' in work_explain:
        work_explain = '物流STAFF'

    for i in works:
        if i in work_explain:
            work = i

　　 return work
```

Comment: これですね。`in`は最後の1つにしかかかりません。[複数の文字列を"in"で含まれているが判定したいですが、、、](https://teratail.com/questions/162961) 対策についてはこちらの方がもう少し詳しく。[【python】複数のin演算子を一つにまとめる方法](https://www.haya-programming.com/entry/2018/05/26/031355)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本題とは無関係な事ですが、カテゴリーを追加していく度に条件分岐の記述が増える事になりますので、カテゴリーリストの様なモノを作成すると良いかと思います。また、複数のカテゴリーに一致する場合には、全てのカテゴリーを列挙する方が適切ではないでしょうか。

```
## { category: [keyword, ...], ... } 
WORK_CATEGORIES = {
  '箱詰め': ['箱づめ'],
  '品出し': ['品だし'],
  'シール貼り': ['シールはり'],
  '資材運搬': ['資材運び', '資材を運ぶ'],
  '物流STAFF': [
    '物流staff', '工場staff', '工場STAFF', '物流倉庫',
    '倉庫業務', '倉庫内作業',
  ],
}

def get_work_category(work_explain):
  return [
    category for category, keywords in WORK_CATEGORIES.items() for word in keywords
    if word in work_explain or category in work_explain
  ]


if __name__ == '__main__':

  explains = [
    '【シール貼り/おまけ付け】登録制★来社不要のWEB登録♪日払い',
    '【倉庫内作業】登録制「Wワーク・学校の合間を有効活用◆」',
    '【資材運び】物流倉庫/要フォークリフト免許',
    '【引越し】単発1日作業、その日払い',
  ]

  for exp in explains:
    c = get_work_category(exp)
    print('{}\n=> {}\n'.format(exp, ','.join(c) if c else 'None matches.'))
```

**実行結果**

```
【シール貼り/おまけ付け】登録制★来社不要のWEB登録♪日払い
=> シール貼り

【倉庫内作業】登録制「Wワーク・学校の合間を有効活用◆」
=> 物流STAFF

【資材運び】物流倉庫/要フォークリフト免許
=> 資材運搬,物流STAFF

【引越し】単発1日作業、その日払い
=> None matches.
```

Answer (score 3):

コメントで紹介した1つ目の記事を元に考えると以下の行は、

```
if "資材運び" or "資材を運ぶ" in work_explain:

if '工場STAFF' or '物流倉庫' or '倉庫業務' or '工場staff' or '倉庫内作業' in work_explain:
```

この形と判断され、最初が文字列定数なので必ず`True`になり、'資材運搬'も'物流STAFF'も順番に代入されて、最後の`if`で代入された'物流STAFF'が有効になります。

```
if ("資材運び") or ("資材を運ぶ" in work_explain):

if ('工場STAFF') or ('物流倉庫') or ('倉庫業務') or ('工場staff') or ('倉庫内作業' in work_explain):
```

コメントで紹介した2つ目の記事の対策を適用すると以下のようになります。

```
work_explain1 ='【シール貼り/おまけ付け】登録制★来社不要のWEB登録♪日払い'
work_explain2 ='【倉庫内作業】登録制「Wワーク・学校の合間を有効活用◆'
work_explain3 ='Webコンテンツの品質管理を行う部署'
work_explain4 ='お掃除・片付けが主な作業です デパート内で軽い資材運び 装飾品の片付け'

def work_category(work_explain):

    works = ['箱詰め','組付','袋詰め','検査','資材運搬','ガスの充填',
    '包装','景品交換','品質管理','ドライバー助手','鮮魚スタッフ','配送アシスタント',
    '食品加工','調理補助','荷下ろし', '荷捌き','資材運搬','施工管理','地盤改良',
    '中古住宅インスペクション','清掃','地盤調査','物流STAFF','タオルたたみ','ペットボトルの分別']

    if  '箱づめ' in work_explain:
        work_explain = '箱詰め'
    if  '品だし' in work_explain:
        work_explain = '品出し'

    if any(map(work_explain.__contains__, ('資材運び','資材を運ぶ'))):  # 記事適用
        work_explain = '資材運搬'
    if any(map(work_explain.__contains__, ('工場STAFF','物流倉庫','倉庫業務','工場staff','倉庫内作業'))):  # 記事適用
        work_explain = '物流STAFF'

    work = ''  # あらかじめforの外で宣言・初期化が必要なはず
    for i in works:
        if i in work_explain:
            work = i

    return work

print(work_category(work_explain1))  # 何も合致しないので空文字列
print(work_category(work_explain2))  # 物流STAFF
print(work_category(work_explain3))  # 品質管理
print(work_category(work_explain4))  # 資材運搬
```